# npm install does not install the dependencies of individual node modules into the respective node modules folders

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

npm install was installing node modules correctly until recently when I ran into a bug. Now, npm install does not install the dependencies of individual node modules into the respective node modules folders.

[image: Screenshot]

See screenshot for what I mean.
The finder window at the forefront shows the correct npm install before the bug. npm install express would download and put the files in correct folders. The accepts folder is a node module of express and has its own node modules, mime types and negotiator.

Now, the accepts folder and its own node modules sit out at the same level as express folder. As seen in the finder window in the back.

This is causing me not to be able to upload to heroku.

Please advise on how to fix.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-muse-examples-webgui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "An example on how to use the node-muse module in a web interface.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ShaPOC/node-muse/tree/master/examples/webgui"
  },
  "author": "Jimmy Aupperlee <j.aup.gt@gmail.com>",
  "license": "GPLv3",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "leapjs": "^0.6.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.7",
    "node-muse": "^0.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: could you share your package.json as well? also have you tried to npm install accepts separately?

Comment: Yes, tried doing it separately. Same problem, installing everything at the same level. Updated with package.json

Comment: Did the suggested solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is not a bug, it actually is a new behavior introduced with npm@3.

That normally should not cause any conflict or problems, but if it does in your case try to install it with

```
npm install --legacy-bundling
```

instead, so delete the whole node_modules folder and reinstall it with that command.